# Consulta SQL Retornado Nulo, Vazio para JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

estou com problemas!! tenho duas tabelas 'usuario'e 'post' quando uso o phpmyadmin para fazer a seguinte consulta ele me retorna os valores como eu espero.

```
SELECT usuario.nome, usuario.foto_profile, post.titulo, post.descricao, post.local, post.latitude, post.longitude, post.data
FROM usuario
INNER JOIN post ON usuario.id = post.id_usuario
```

[image: consulta]

porém quando vou fazer com php não me retorna nada e pior nem se quer um erro.
segue o código utilizado.

```
// Instancia o objeto PDO
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
// define para que o PDO lance exceções caso ocorra erros
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


// executa a instrução SQL
$consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT usuario.id,usuario.nome, usuario.foto_profile, post.titulo, post.descricao, post.local, post.latitude, post.longitude, post.data
FROM usuario
INNER JOIN post ON usuario.id = post.id_usuario");

$results = array();
while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // aqui eu mostro os valores de minha consulta
  $results['feed'][] = array(
      'nome' => $linha['nome'],
      'foto_perfil' => $linha['foto_profile'],
      'timestamp' => $linha['data'],
      'titulo' => $linha['local'],
      'descricao' => $linha['descricao'],
   );
}


echo json_encode($results);
```

obs: estranho é quando eu tiro o titulo e a descrição ele me retorna o nome, foto_perfil e o timestamp

```
{
    "feed": [{
        "nome": "Alessandro Barreto",
        "foto_perfil": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/-fgg69tRzubc\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAEA\/fU9pzVn2CO8\/photo.jpg",
        "timestamp": "1448069250858"
    }, {
        "nome": "Alessandro Barreto",
        "foto_perfil": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/-fgg69tRzubc\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAEA\/fU9pzVn2CO8\/photo.jpg",
        "timestamp": "1448069704176"
    }, {
        "nome": "Alessandro Barreto",
        "foto_perfil": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/-fgg69tRzubc\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAEA\/fU9pzVn2CO8\/photo.jpg",
        "timestamp": "1448069737468"
    },
```

Comment: Ele não retorna nada do banco para aplicação ou retorna normal e quando vai criar o json ele cria o json em branco?

Comment: quando eu eu tento retornar normal (só printando os valores )sem usar o json ele funciona, porém o estranho é quando eu tento montar o json e colocar informações da tabela 'post' ele vem vazio

Comment: Pode ser algum valor dentro de alguma string quebrando o json, tenta pegar o valor de uma linha (where usuario.id = X) e tenta montar o Json.

Comment: continua do mesmo jeito vazio, fiz um teste fazendo o print "print_r($results);" e ele me retornou os valores mas no json_encode não vem vazio

Comment: Tenta colocar assim echo json_encode(utf8_encode($results));

Comment: Ricardo ele da erro "Warning: utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in"

Comment: Então coloca ela para executar para cada string que vai entrar no array. Se não der então fico sem ideias.

Comment: Ricardo fiz o seguinte coloquei o utf8_encode($linha['titulp])  em cada linha da consulta e deu certo, valeeeeu

Comment: Coloquei o resultado da conversa na resposta para ficar mais fácil de outras pessoas resolverem o problema. Se quiser marca como resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colocando na resposta o resultado dos comentários:

Para o Json funcionar no PHP é necessário encode utf8.

No caso acima bastas colocar utf8_encode(string), nas strings vindas da consulta na hora de montar o array, com isso todo o array vai estar no formato correto e a conversão para o Json vai funcionar.

Comment: O json funciona com ou sem uso do utf8_encode(). O problema no seu caso é a falta de configuração do ambiente e, por isso precisou fazer essa "gambiarra" com utf8_encode()..